# writing a file streaming client for WCF

Tags: wcf, tcp, embedded, client, large-files

I'm working on a project to create gprs connected embedded devices.

I need a service that all the embedded devices can report to and regularly download large files from.
I'm considering using [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) as it's a nice out of the box solution and will scale well if I design it properly.
I was going to use a rest service for data upload (2 -3 calls with 8 params) and some file streaming for the download of the file ( 1-5mb).

The problem is I'm not sure how to implement the client
Now I know how to write a rest client (easy) but not how to write a file streaming client for WCF. 
Does anyone think this is the right way to go? Would I be better off implementing my own TCP server as I've got to write the embedded side from the modem driver up?
Thanks
Ronan

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a simple IIS Server to server files via HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

WCF sounds like quite a large package. For an embedded device, you should probably keep it simple. Pick from the well-known Internet protocols. On the server side, you have your choice of standard server software. On the embedded side, you may be able to purchase ready-made solutions, or else implement a well-documented standard protocol yourself.

For file streaming, over TCP/IP, you could use HTTP. (You could also use FTP but I can't think of advantages of using that over HTTP.)

If you want to go for simpler embedded implementation, and use UDP, you could try [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol). I've used that in the past on a modem device, since we used UDP for the main communications, and thus wanted to use UDP (avoid adding TCP) for file transfers (embedded firmware upgrades). TFTP is quite straight-forward to implement on an embedded device.